# Java Design Patterns: Facade

Tags: java, design-patterns, facade

I'm trying to make a simple ordering system, and because it's an assignment it is a delimitation that I shouldn't make DB and GUI, but I need to implement at least 4 design patterns. One of my decisions was to use Facade. As far as I understand the Facade class is kind of controller and this is what i have so far:

```
package model;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Facade {
ClientsList clients;
OrdersList orders;
ProductsList products;
ArrayList<Orders> orderlist;
public Facade() {
    clients = new ClientsList();
    orderlist=new ArrayList<Orders>();
    orders = new OrdersList(orderlist);
    products = new ProductsList();

}

public int ClientsSize() {

    return clients.size();
}

public int OrdersSize() {

    return orders.size();
}

public void addClients(Clients client) {
    clients.add(client);

}

public void addOrders(Orders order) {
    orders.add(order);
}

public void removeClients() {
    clients.remove();

}

public void removeOrders() {
    orders.remove();

}

public String next() {
    return orders.it();
}
}
```

The other classes in my model package are Orders, OrdersList, Clients, Clientslist, Products and ProductsList and in the *List classes I'm holding the infromation in ArrayList. So my question is: is this code a Facade?

Answer (score 1):

A facade is supposed to shield me from knowing about certain classes and the operations they implement. In your example, I may not need to know about ClientList but I do need to know about Client, Product and Order.  It would be better if those classes were hidden away from me so I just need to talk to the facade.

Answer (score 1):

Write an additional interface so developers dont have to work with the implementation of your facade:

```
public interface OrderService {
    //methods your co-developers should be able to use
}

public class Facade implements OrderService {
    //methods your co-developers dont want to know about
}
```

In your code use the interface and not the impl.

Comment: The weird thing is that i've seen several examples and books that describes the Facade pattern without even mentioning this. It otherwise a crucial OO princilple. +1 for the mentioning it. As an example: http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/facade/java/1

Answer (score 0):

The goal of a facade is to shield the implementation of functionality in a certain component. A facade normally provides an interface to 'the outside world'. I don't know the rest of your code, but the above example *could* be a facade.

Say you are building a component which fetches message from social media. You could build a facade with a method 'GetMessage(string keyword)' which (obviously) returns a list of messages, regardless of the social media source. The *client* of this component doesn't care *how* the component gets data from social media, he just wants messages. Methods like 'SearchFacebook' or 'SearchTwitter' can be hidden, as the client has no interest in  calling these methods. However, 'GetMessages' can use them to search Facebook and Twitter, build a list of the results of those two and return it to the client.

For another good example, check the wiki page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern

Answer (score 0):

Intent of facade:

1. Provide a unified interface to a set of interfaces in a subsystem. Facade defines a higher-level interface that makes the subsystem easier to use.
2. Wrap a complicated subsystem with a simpler interface.

The functionality you are providing are matching with above points, so from my view It is a Facade.

In your example you are exposing sub-system(OrdersList, ProductsList) functionality though Facade.

Answer (score 0):

To get more knowledge about facade design pattern, read "Head First Design Patterns"